# Evolution repeating error message every few minutes

Tags: email, evolution

I have Evolution mail configured to outlook, all is working well except for a repeating "Error/Warning" message every couple of minutes of the day.

[image]

Reason for Error, I tried to delete all the JUNK mail at once :(

Can anyone tell me if there is a simple way to stop this message showing as it is very annoying?

Thanks in advance

G

Comment: I think [assumption only] this error repeats because it keeps trying to comply with your prior [delete] request (I did the same years ago). I got annoyed at the [repeated] error, so exited [evolution] and went & deleted the junk.mail file(s) from shell, then forced evolution to re-create its indexes & my [warning] message disappeared. This however was years ago, so I don't recall how (just a dirty-hack), and you may have a different message & cause.  *(note: I didn't use exchange.server; some mail had been imported from outlook but I'm ignoring your outlook ref.)*

Comment: I will try if nobody else can suggest a cleaner way, thanks for input.